# How can you customize your terminal bash prompt with smiley faces?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal.app

I'm trying to figure out how I can customize my terminal's bash prompt to use smiley faces. What I want (as seen in the example blow) is for the cwd to be separated from the prompt by a \n and show a green smiley face if the command succeeded, and a red sad face if it failed.

Any ideas?

This was inspired by a Peepcode screencast.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After spending about a half hour playing around with andhrimnir's code and doing further research, I finally got what I wanted.

```
PS1="\w \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e '\[\e[01;32m\]\n\xE2\x98\xBA'; else echo -e '\[\e[01;31m\]\n\xE2\x98\xB9'; fi\` \[\e[01;34m\]\[\e[00m\]"
```

You can find a [list of emoticons here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf) and then [convert them](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) to the 3-digit byte code you see after the newline character.

To get the `cwd`, all I had to do was use `\w`. You could also show the current user by doing `\u@\w`, which would output something like `joshsmith@~`.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the smiley face shown above is unicode character `0x263a`. So you'll need a unicode-capable terminal (Not sure if terminal.app supports this, I imagine it does though).

Here's sample code that prints a green smiley face for return codes of 0 and red frown faces otherwise.

```
PS1="\[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h \[\e[01;34m\]\W \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e '\[\e[01;32m\]:)'; else echo -e '\[\e[01;31m\]:('; fi\` \[\e[01;34m\]$\[\e[00m\]"
```

Credit goes to Fingel on the Arch forums (he posted it [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=50885&p=11)).

Comment: Awesome work on the if/then sample. I'm curious how to do the newline, remove the `$`, actually use the Unicode symbol, and make it show the full `cwd`.

Comment: ...and an hour later, answered my own question (thanks to you!).

Comment: Glad I could help! There's a lot of info in the thread at the link I posted above if you want to get deeper into custom `$PS1` stuff.

Comment: Yeah, half of my research started at that thread. Super helpful. Also, for anyone that wants to go more in-depth on the command line, Peepcode has a great advanced screencast.