# ASCII smiley code used for the main character in Rogue

Tags: characters, ascii, smiles

What is the terminal code for the old square ASCII character used in the original Rogue game?

Here's a game that uses it as its main character:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZIzCGir58Y&feature=related

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/368497/how-can-you-customize-your-terminal-bash-prompt-with-smiley-faces).

Comment: Not really, because that's a different character, apparently. The dos console doesn't recognize it when I paste it in.

Edit: Actually, it worked ok in dos, just not in Notepad with the Terminal font.

Comment: A smiley face *is not* a character in standard [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: @Nick And that's why I only linked to it, instead of voting to close your question as duplicate.

Comment: It would be a good question to investigate why terminals display the SOH and SOT characters as smileys, and the history in that tradition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That chars equals to SOH (White face) & SOT (Black Face)

```
Binary  Oct Dec Hex Abbr    [a] [b]    Name
000 0001    001 1   01  SOH ␁   ^A     Start of Header
000 0010    002 2   02  STX ␂   ^B     Start of Text
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The display system for the original IBM PC in text mode had a very simple memory mapping for the 80x24 text screen. You could poke values into bytes in a certain area of memory and characters would appear on the display. The characters for each byte value were determined by a video ROM which had bitmapped display characters for all 256 values of each byte. This included displayable characters for ASCII control characters (0-31).

Many contemporary printers had the same character set and could often be set into a literal-print mode where these control characters were printed rather than acted on (a carriage return would be printed as a character, it would not cause the print head to return to the left edge of the paper).

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)